# How do I find out if my system is using Mir?

Tags: mir

I've just installed Mir and I'm wondering if I'm actually running it or if it fell back to X. How can I tell if Mir is running?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> You can also simply check if the system compositor process is running:
>
> ```
>  ps afx | grep unity-system-compositor
> ```

On my system running Mir it returns something like this:

```
jorge@jillociraptor:~$ ps afx | grep unity-system-compositor
 4260 pts/0    S+     0:00          |   |               \_ grep --color=auto unity-system-compositor
 1606 ?        S      0:00 /usr/sbin/unity-system-compositor --from-dm-fd 9 --to-dm-fd 13 --vt 7
```

Machines NOT running Mir will not show `unity-system-compositor` running.

Reference:

- [Running Mir](http://www.olli-ries.com/running-mir/) - Olli Reis

Comment: You can also use `ps -e | grep unity-system-compositor` to avoid matching `grep` itself. With this, no output will be shown if Mir is not running.

Comment: @minerz029 Running Jorge's Command, I get 4868 pts/4    S+     0:00                  \_ grep --color=auto unity-system-compositor
    Running your command, I get nothing. So I am confused.

Answer (score 2):

```
ps -e | grep unity-system-co
```

Will return one response if Mir is running, nothing if it is not.  This is because 'ps -e' actually truncates the process names to 15 characters (known upstream bug/limitation).  I found the suggestion from minerz029 always returned nothing even if Mir was running.

Comment: Why would anyone use `ps | grep` when the command `pgrep` exists? Try `pgrep -fa unity-system-compositor`.

Answer (score 0):

It's going to depend on what you mean by "I just installed Mir".  Mir is really just a set of libraries.  There are client libraries and server libraries.  There are also several different packages that provide actual Mir server binaries.

There is a demo Mir server, but if you were running it you would know, because you'd have switched to a VT and typed in the command to run it.  That server is found in the mir-demos package.

There's the Unity 8 Mir server.  It runs as a part of Unity 8 (package unity8).  You'd know you were running that because your desktop would look like a Unity 8 desktop.

Finally, there is the unity-system-compositor Mir server, which is generally started by LightDM.  Unless you wrote your own LightDM integration scripts, you either need to install the Unity 8 desktop session (package unity8-desktop-session-mir), in which case the only way to run the Mir server is to log in to the Unity 8 desktop, or you installed the ubuntu-desktop-mir package, in which case the other answers are correct:  a `ps` will show the unity-system-compositor running underneath the X server.